# autopopulate the value in a grid (ProcessMaker)

Tags: javascript, processmaker

Hello I am working on a process maker 3.0
where i have 2 task.I want to display field value from task 1 into grid which is there in task2
how do i auto populate the grid in Processmaker
here is i tried to write some trigger on task 2.

```
 getGridField("clientGrid", 1, "txtData").value = "0";
echo 'dddddddd';
```

where is clientGrid is the id of the grid and txtData is name of a text field inside the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just displaying the grid, I can recommend this:
1. create a Grid type Variable in the Process Variables.
2. associate the grid on task 1 to that variable
3. associate the grid on task 2 to the same variable - it will need to have the controls named the same as the grid in task 1 to display the values.

Answer (score 1):

I think this information can be important for you for populating grids

https://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Grid_Control#PHP_in_Grids

At his link, you will find how a grid behaves in structure. It is an associative array with many associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you try Javascript on 3.0, I would suggest you use the Jquery build in function: [Refer here](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/JavaScript_Functions_and_Methods#grid.setValue) for grids and
here for getting the [value of the field](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/JavaScript_Functions_and_Methods#control.getValue)

You can also use trigger to do it but it must be set on the 2nd Form, Before Dynaform.

You can refer to this code: (You have Item, Amount and Vendor as a ordinary field in the 1st Dynaform and wants it to be in the grid in the second)

```
$item = @@item;
$amount = @@amount;
$vendor = @@vendor;

@=grid_item = array(
     1 => array('item'=>$item,  'amount'=>$amount, 'vendor' => $vendor)
);
```

For Javascript:

```
var item= $("#item").getValue();
var amount= $("#amount").getValue();
var vendor = $("#amount").getValue();

//inserting value in the grid 
//jQuery("#grid").setValue(value, row, col); syntax
jQuery("#grid_item").setValue(item, '1', '1');
jQuery("#grid_item").setValue(amount, '1', '2');
jQuery("#grid_item").setValue(vendor, '1', '3');
```

To make it more efficient in the JS process, use loop and all my codes are subject for debugging as I just create  my code base on the wiki.